# Sum values against an item in 2-D python list

Tags: python, list

I have a 2-D list like this:

```
myList = [ ['A', 1], ['B', 1], ['C', 3], ['A', -1], ['B', 1], ['D', 2] ];
```

And I would like to have the following result:

```
mySum = [ ['A', 0], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 2] ];
```

Tried my best, but somehow can't find any reasonably elegant answer yet!

Comment: To be honest, I only have gibberish so far to this problem. Trying to write a sentiment analyzer and scoring words for the metric I designed; if that adds anything further to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty straight forward binning operation.  A `collections.defaultdict` will work beautifully:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

for k, v in myList:
    d[k] += v

print d.items()  # print(list(d.items())) on python3.x
```

Basically, the dict holds the bins (`'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, ...) and a value (the current sum in that bin).  We use a `defaultdict` because if a bin is missing, it will immediately create it when necessary (with an initial value of 0).  As you iterate over the list, you look up the bin's value, sum the current value with the value already in the bin and then you put the new value back in the bin.